# How to delete a specific cell in a csv file when the contents is said in an input in python

Tags: python, file, csv

```
    elif addordelete = "delete":
         whichdelete = input("What thing do you want to delete? ")
```

[GameCharacter.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqbqB.png)

I want to know how to delete a specific cell in a csv file through a python input.

For example if the user in the python program says that they want to delete MP40 from the file, then it should delete. Can someone explain how to do this in simple terms as possible (I'm kind of a python noob. Code is appreciated.

Comment: if you provide me some csv example lines I can write a snippet of code

Comment: What do you mean by this? Do you want my entire code or do you want the CSV file itself? The CSV file is already in my post.

Comment: the csv you posted is an image.. I would like a copypaste of the csv content, just two or three lines

Comment: Weapons: MP40 Scar20 STG-44 M1A1 Carbine M2-A1 Flamethrower 
Browning M1918A2 Grenade                   
                                                                                                             Outfit: Body Armour Bullet-Proof Vest Helmet Trench Boots

Comment: I've added some code below

Comment: Why would you want to delete it in the file? The obvious container to keep a collection of unique items for me is a `set`, which allows easy deletion

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to import the whole [CSV](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) into python, process it and saving it back to file.

Here's a simple snippet which opens the `CSV`, processes it asking what you want to delete, then saves it back again.

 You can start from this code to get what you need.

```
import csv


try:
    csvfile = open('testcsv.csv','rb')
    table = [row for row in csv.reader(csvfile)] #further parameters such as delimiters on doc
    whichdelete = whichdelete = input("What thing do you want to delete? ")
    header = table.pop(0) #remove header and save it to header variable
    res = [row for row in table if whichdelete not in row] #save result without the row you want to delete
    csvfile.close()
except IOError:
    print "File not found"
    quit()

try:
    resultFile = open('resultCSV.csv','wb+')
    writer = csv.writer(resultFile)
    writer.writerow(header)
    for row in res:
        writer.writerow(row)
    resultFile.close()

except IOError:
    print "Error creating result file"
    quit()
```